# Another RegEx with negation

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Looks like a simple problem but I can't figure out the solution. I was hoping negative lookahead would help but it doesn't appear so. 
In a string like this:

```
AYB AXZB AZB
```

i'm looking to match the combination of A and B with X between them, and anything else but **not** another A or B. That is, I should be able to find 'AXZB' only in above line. 
A, X and B not just characters in the real-life example, so negation is not an option.

**Update:**

Clarifying the requirements - as stated above, A, X, and B are not just characters but multi-character patterns, so `[^AB]` is not an option

**Correct Answer:**

```
(A(?:(?!(A|B)).)*?X(?:(?!(A|B)).)*?B)
```

Comment: What are the rules? `AYB` and `AZB` don't have another `A` or `B` between them .. If `X` has to reside, you could probably do [`A[^AB]*X[^AB]*B`](https://regex101.com/r/lN1xN9/1)

Comment: You mean this `\bA\S*X\S*B\b` ?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean..

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Should it not find "AAXB"? Must "A" and "B" be first/last?

Comment: AYB and AZB don't have X between them, so they don't match. AAXB should not match, but AXB should.

Comment: I'm using Java, but I think language is not relevant here

Comment: Can you give an example of what A and B might look like as multi-character patterns?

Comment: <A> and <B>, as an example what can be instead of A and B

Comment: please provide a real example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>how about this simple pattern</s>

```
A\S*X\S*B
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/169)

---

based on the comment below use this pattern

```
(A(?:(?!A).)*?X(?:(?!B).)*?B)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/169)

Comment: This will not work, as (a) whitespaces are allowed between A and B, and (b) for modified string AYBAXZBAZB this pattern will match the entire string

Comment: @AndreiM, Updated above

Comment: Thanks @alpha bravo, you got very close to the correct answer, I slightly modified and accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `/a[^ab\s]?x[^ab\s]?b/i`.  This will match any "a" then any characters (except another "a", "b", or a space) until a "b" as long as there is an "x" in there somewhere.

Here's a example using JavaScript.

```js
var string = 'AyB AXB AxB blabla'; // change this string to test the regex

if (string.match(/a[^ab\s]?x[^ab\s]?b/i)) {
  alert('The string found this match: ' + /a[^ab\s]?x[^ab\s]?b/i.exec(string));
} else {
  alert('There was no match found in the string.');
}
```

Edit and test here: https://regex101.com/r/hO3qY3/2

Comment: This won't work for the reason that A and B are not just characters, per requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\bA(?=\S*?X)[^AB]*?B\b
```

Comment: Sorry but this won't work as A and B are not just characters, so [^AB] is not an option

Answer (score 0):

```
A\S*X\S*B
```

Try this simple regex.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/50